# How to draw a google column chart in angular 6 project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, google-visualization, angular6

I'm using angular 6 and I want to draw a column chart of Google. I found below codes from documantation but I don't know how to use it in my app?

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

**js**

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Move', 'Percentage'],
      ["King's pawn (e4)", 44],
      ["Queen's pawn (d4)", 31],
      ["Knight to King 3 (Nf3)", 12],
      ["Queen's bishop pawn (c4)", 10],
      ['Other', 3]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 800,
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      chart: {
        title: 'Chess opening moves',
        subtitle: 'popularity by percentage' },
      axes: {
        x: {
          0: { side: 'top', label: 'White to move'} // Top x-axis.
        }
      },
      bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first declare in your component like this:

```
declare var google:any;
```

then your component will know what your are refering to when you call

```
google.charts.load..
```

Everything else looks good..